# How do I get a texture painted image to show up on my model?

Tags: texture-painting

I have a body mesh for my monkey, and I uv-ed it! Then I added a new material and opened an image for it in the texture panel! Then I went in to texture paint mode and changed the paint type to image. Then I opened the same texture image I used before with the material! I went to texture paint mode, and the image showed up on the mesh and the uvs! Then I went to object mode and texture viewport shading and it wasn't there! It wasn't there in material mode either! The image shows it in texture paint mode where the image actually shows up. How can I fix this?[image]

Comment: This appears to be a repeat of your question not long before this one.  Please do not repeat questions.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Example Nodes above. Texture Node with the UV on a diffuse shader as the surface output.  With the image texture node the file selection button was pushed and the correct image selected.  There is also a emission plane in the image. If you wanted a different texture you can add another texture node and make the connections or specify a different image with the file selector on the node.

Comment: Ahh thanks it works!!!! But now the texture is too dark. How do I make it lighter?

Comment: In the image above you see the plane with emission material ... a light.  Increase the [strength].  Lets assume your texture is not a light.  Make sure all comments are directly related to a proposed answer.